# Swagger - how attach an example to particular end-point

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, .net-5

I'm working on API where my controllers just returns JsonDocument's instead of DTO's.

I need to provide some response examples for API documentation. But examples should be dedicated for particular end-points.

I've created example provider `IExampleProvider<JsonDocument>` - and unfortunately the example is populated for all JsonDocument's, instead of the only one decorated by the attribute:
`[SwaggerResponseExample(200, typeof(MySpecificResponseExample))]`

Even if attribute mentioned above is not specified, the example documentation is included.

Startup.cs:

```cs
c.ExampleFilters();
c.OperationFilter<AddResponseHeadersFilter>();
```

`services.AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblyOf<Startup>();`

Example provider:

```cs
public class (MySpecificResponseExample))] : IExamplesProvider<JsonDocument>
    {
        public JsonDocument GetExamples()
        {
            return JsonDocument.Parse(@"Example JSON is here.");
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```cs
        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(JsonDocument), 200)]
        [SwaggerResponseExample(200, typeof(MySpecificResponseExample))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomething() {}
```

How to include examples to end-points with specific attribute only? I have another end-point where `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(JsonDocument), 200)]` is specified, but I want to ommit `MySpecificResponseExample`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not return JsonDocument over the http since it needs to be converted to json , so I don't see any sense in double parcing and unparcing you better try this and parse to JsonDocument  when you get it. But I highly recommend to use JObject Or JArray instead

```
 public JsonResult GetExamples()
 {
     return new JsonResult( @"Example JSON is here.");
 }
```

Comment: Ok - I can return JsonResult, but the issue is the same - I have one type which is used in several end-points. I just want to provide the example response for one end-point only. 

Endpoint A - return type `Xyz`, Endpoint B - return type `xyz` as well - I need to provide example response for Endpoint A, but I don't want to have any example for Endpoint B.

Comment: @WymyslonyNick You have to post all chain of the code if you need some help. Not just several lines. And think if you really need a Swagger if you have so many problems with it.